# How do I pass numeric arguments to Latex environments

Tags: latex, numeric

I have defined an environment as

```
\newenvironment{question}[1]
{Question (#1 points):}{}
```

I am using it as

```
\begin{question}[10]
...
\end{question}
```

I get the following error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero
\begin{question}[
                 10]
```

Comment: Instead of re-inventing the wheel, you may want to consider using the "exam" document class: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/exam.html

Comment: **@las3rjock:** I certainly can't for the OP, but *none* of the existing write a test in LaTeX classes quite meet my needs. But I second your advice to look around, there are several such classes on CTAN and they provide quite different sets of features.

Answer (score 7):

The proper syntax is with a curly brace, not a square brace:

```
\begin{question}{10}
What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?
\end{question}
```

Comment: @Martijn: *Psalidoprocne nitens*, to be specific :-D